# Is there any way to crop windows (not images) in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, window-manager

Is there any way to crop windows (not images) in Ubuntu?

(Background: I use "alt click" to move windows, and "alt right click" to quickly resize windows. Not default settings, these require tweaks.)

Example: One might wish to have a small window, e.g BBC live news, or a youtube video, or a long running terminal process, visible in one corner of the monitor.

Seeking a way to crop an application's window, so that only the desired part of the application is visible - in exactly the same way one would crop an image.

I suspect an alternative window manager would be required.